# Zipkin and Sleuth integration for non spring boot projects

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

Can anyone tell me, is there any way to **integrate Zipkin (if possible Sleuth also) for non-spring boot projects**?

I am trying to integrate Zipkin for my traditional spring application. It is not a microservice. How could I do this? Any suggestions, please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use e.g. openzipkin Brave project or Opentelemetry projects directly. Sleuth works only with boot based projects